# int vs size_t vs long

Tags: c, integer, long-integer, size-t

I have been seeing a lot of people lately say that you should use `size_t` instead of `int`. But what is the difference? Is it always better? Or are there situations for `int`, and situations for `size_t`? Or maybe `size_t` is similar to `long`? When should I use `int`, when should I use `size_t`, and when should I use `long?`

Comment: The `sizeof` operator returns a `size_t` : you are allowed to cast it, e.g. `(int)sizeof("abcd")` is 5. Depending on the implementation, it could be an `unsigned short` (unlikely), `unsigned int` or `unsigned long` or `unsigned intptr_t`

Comment: See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/c

Comment: Use `int` when you need to field a potential negative return value, such as EOF.  `size_t` is unsigned, so a variable create as type `size_t` cannot contain a negative, but completely suitable for creating a container that will simply represent the size of a variable, or other C object that is measurable in `bytes`. For example to test the size of an `int` on your system, you could do this:  `size_t bytes = sizeof(int);`

Comment: Couldn't I just use int for any size_t situation? Or is size_t just better for that?

Comment: As Basile already mentioned above, `size_t` can be one of multiple integer types. That means,  `size_t` might be larger than `int`. And even if it is same size, it can hold larger values than `int` because it is unsigned. If you just use `int` everywhere, how would those values fit?

Comment: _Couldn't I just use int for any size_t situation? "_.  Yes you could, but it would not be optimal for the reasons already stated.  FWIW, and at the risk of sounding redundant, it is idiomatic to use `size_t` for `size_t` situations.

Comment: C language has chosen not to specify the size of the basic integral types. For that reason, it uses a number of additional types which generally end in being a synonym for a basic type (but there is no guarantee here). The rule is that the programmer should use the most relevant type: `int` for common integer signed operations, `unsigned` for common positive integer operations, `size_t` when you handle file or memory sizes, `time_t` when you handle times, and so on... The rule of thumb is to care for what an operator (e.g. `size_of`) or a function (e.g. `time`) is declared to return.

Comment: Safety of ptrdiff_t and size_t types in address arithmetic: https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/posts/cpp/a0050/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it (`size_t`) always better?

Usually

---

- `int` math may fail size calculation that woks with `size_t` math.

```
    int r = rand();
    int c = rand();
    char *ptr1 = malloc(r * c); // Overflow possible
    char *ptr2 = malloc((size_t) 1 * r*c); // Overflow possible, yet less likely.
```

---

- `int` range may be (and often is) less than `size_t` range.

When `sizeof some_object` exceeds `INT_MAX`, following code will certainly lead to errors.

```
int sz = sizeof some_object;  // Problem when size is large.
// Good as
size_t sz = sizeof some_object;  // No problem for all sizeof return values.
```

---

- `unsigned` range may be less than `size_t` range.

String lengths may be longer than `UINT_MAX`

```
unsigned sz = strlen(pointer_to_a_string); // Problem when length is large.
// Good as
size_t sz = strlen(pointer_to_a_string); // No problem for all values from strlen().
```

---

- `size_t` is an *unsigned* type, so avoid tests like `size >= 0`, `size < 0`, `size == -1`.

When code decrements the size below zero, we have issues.

```
// Compare
int isize = sizeof object;  // Bad as size may exceed INT_MAX
while (isize >= 0) {
  ...
  isize--;
}
size_t usize = sizeof object;
while (usize >= 0) {  // Bad as usize >= 0 is _always_ true
  ...
  usize--;
}
```

Instead re-work code in some fashion.

```
size_t usize = sizeof object;
do {
  ...
} while (usize-- > 0):
```

Answer (score 4):

The main reason is self-documenting code. `size_t` is used exclusively for the purpose of describing the size of things.

But there are also some practical advantages of using `size_t` over `int`:

- Array/object sizes are always unsigned and positive and should therefore be represented by an unsigned type. Using a negative value as array size is always a bug. Using a negative value as array index is also problematic since it is hard to read, *probably* also a bug.
- `int` may overflow in certain scenarios when it is not large enough to contain a requested size. `size_t` is guaranteed to be at least large enough to contain the size of the largest supported object.
- `int` may be subject to implicit promotion in case it is mixed with larger operands in the same expression.
- `int` is further problematic if used to represent addresses, or if used to store the results of pointer arithmetic. Here there are other more suitable types like `uintptr_t` and `ptrdiff_t` respectively.

`size_t` therefore provides better compatibility with the `sizeof` operator as well as various standard library functions (like for example `strlen`). Mostly these problems get exposed when porting sloppily written code using `int` into 64 bit systems.

However `size_t` is not without problems either, since its size is unknown. In certain scenarios like hardware-related programming, the fixed width types in `stdint.h` might be more suitable to use than `size_t`, or you might risk getting a type that is too large.

Some old C libs also had bad compliance and weren't properly supporting `%zu` for the printf/scanf family of functions.

Comment: `size + modifier` would only pose a problem on soon officially unsupported non two's complement architectures.

Comment: @chqrlie No, the problem here is the accidental conversion from a small negative value to a large positive value caused by implicit promotion.

Comment: I understand that, but provided `size` is greater or equal to `-modifier`, the expression evaluates to the expected value.

Comment: @chqrlie Oh I see what you mean. Yeah that ought to be well-defined, 2's complement or not. Maybe not the best example.

Comment: I removed the example since it was not the best one.

Comment: @Lundin OK, yet "int may be subject to implicit promotion in case it is mixed with larger operands in the same expression." applies to `size_t` too and is not really a problem.  Perhaps the concern is more of a _mixed_ sign-ness one.